# How to avoid a trailing/extra comma when creating a comma-delimited string from array data?

Tags: php, xml, arrays, wordpress, list

I am really new with PHP and all I have to do is to take all selected values and print them out separating them with comma, however, I need to drop last comma after last item in list.

```
<?php $favoriteFruit = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Favorite Fruit', false) ?>
<?php if ($favoriteFruit != null): ?>
    <attribute key="FavoriteFruit" 
               value="<?php foreach($favoriteFruit as $fruit){
                                    echo $fruit.',';
                            } ?>"
               />
<?php endif ?>
```

This one prints out all items in list and doesn't drop last comma. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about simply imploding the array, using a comma as delimiter:

```
<?php echo implode(',',$favoriteFruit);?>
```

---

Just for fun: since people pointed out you can keep the loop and use `rtrim`, and -thankfuly, advised against it. Here's another needlessly complex and absurd approach that works, too:

```
echo vsprintf('%s'.str_repeat(',%s',(count($favoriteFruit)-1)),$favoriteFruit);
//or, the other way round:
echo vsprintf(str_repeat('%s,',(count($favoriteFruit)-1)).'%s',$favoriteFruit);
```

Whatever you do, don't use this code.

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways to do this. The easiest way is to use [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode), by changing this:

```
foreach($favoriteFruit as $fruit){echo $fruit.',';}
```

To:

```
echo implode( ',', $favoriteFruit);
```

The alternative is to use [`rtrim()`](http://php.net/rtrim) to trim off the comma from the right hand side of the string, but since you have an array, you'd have to form the string yourself, like so:

```
$str = '';
foreach($favoriteFruit as $fruit){ $str .= $fruit .',';} 
echo rtrim( $str, ',');
```

That being said, I would recommend using `implode()` as it's easy, simple, and straightforward.

Comment: "I would recommend using explode()"... typo?

Comment: Third option... display the comma before the fruit, unless it's the very first entry in the array

Answer (score 1):

You can use [implode()](http://php.net/implode) instead of [foreach()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

```
<?php $favoriteFruit = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Favorite Fruit', false) ?>
<?php if ($favoriteFruit != null): ?><attribute key="FavoriteFruit" value="<?php echo implode(",", $favoriteFruit);?>" /><?php endif ?>
```

---

I changed this:

```
<?php foreach($favoriteFruit as $fruit){echo $fruit.',';}?>
```

To this:

```
<?php echo implode(",", $favoriteFruit);?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `imlpode` function (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)
or `join` (it is actually synonym of `implode`) (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.join.php)

Comment: best use implode, since its counterpart `explode` isn't depreciated, and doesn't rely on regex, unlike `split`. Also, `join` and `split` remind me of JavaScript, a language that requires a different approach to coding, best to keep those two worlds seperate, IMHO